# bash recursive CSV parser

Tags: bash, csv, awk, recursive-descent

I have moved this question to **[code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/11727/need-some-advice-or-help-with-translation-and-or-testing-csv-recursive-parser-i)**

I've written a recursive descent parser in bash.

I'm wondering if you can point out something helpful to me. It supports backslash escapes and quoted fields with parse error reporting.

The script works like `cut` in some ways.. taking input from file or `stdin` allowing the user to select which line and which field they would like printed out. using options `-l` and `-f` respectively. A list of fields can be printed and a custom delimiter for that list can be specified using options --list '1 2 3 4 5' and --list-seperator $'\n' for example.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob; # we need maxiumum expression capabilities enabled

# option variables
declare list='' delim=$'\n' field='' lineNum=1;

while [[ ${1:0:1} = '-' ]]; do # Parse user arguments

    case $1 in
        -f)
            field=$2; shift 2;
        ;;
        -l)
            lineNum=$2; shift 2;
        ;;
        --list-seperator)
            delim="$2"; shift 2;
        ;;
        --list)
            list="$2"; shift 2;
        ;;
        *) break;;
    esac

done

# open a user supplied file on stdin
[[ -e "$1" ]] && exec 0<$1;

# data from 'read/getline'
declare input='';

# we are using sed to optimize input, the command just prints the desired line
read -r input < <(sed -n ${lineNum}p) 
# why doesn't the above work as a pipe into read?

# range of this line
declare strLen=${#input} value='';

# data processing variables
declare symbol='' value='';

# REGEX symbol "classes"
declare nothing='' comma='[,]' quote='["]' backslash='[\]' text='[^,\"]';

# integers:
declare -i iPos=-1 tPos=0;

# output array:
declare -a items=();

NextSymbol() {

    symbol="${input:$((++iPos)):1}"; # get next char from string

    (( iPos < strLen )); # return false if we are out of range

}

Accept() {

    [[ -z "$symbol" && -z "$1" ]] && return 0; # accept "nothing/empty"

    # if you can meld the above line into the next line
    # let me know: pc.wiz.tt@gmail.com; this is some kind of bug!
    # becare careful because expect expects 'nothing' to be empty.
    # that's why it says 'end of input'

    [[ "$symbol" =~ ^$1$ ]] && NextSymbol && return 0; # match symbol
}

Expect() {
    Accept "$1" && return
    local msg="$0: parse failure: line $lineNum: expected symbol: "
    echo "$msg'${1:-end of input}'" >&2;
    echo "$0: found: '$symbol'" >&2;
    exit 1;
}

value() {

    while Accept $text; do # symbol will not be what we expect here
        value+=${input:$((iPos-1)):1}; # so get what we expect
    done

    Accept $nothing && { # this will only happen at end of the string
        value+=${input:$((iPos-1)):1} # get the last char
        pushValue; # push the data into the array
    }

}

pushValue() {
    items[tPos++]=$value;
    value=''; # clear value!
}

quote() {

    until [[ $symbol =~ $quote || -z $symbol ]]; do
        value+=$symbol;
        NextSymbol;
    done

    Expect $quote;

}

line() {

    Accept $quote && {
        quote
        line;
    }

    Accept $backslash && {
        value+=$symbol;
        NextSymbol;
        value;
        line;
    }

    Accept $comma && {
        pushValue;
        line;
    }

    Accept $text && {
        value=${input:$((iPos-1)):1};
        value;
        line;
    }

}

NextSymbol;
    line;
        Expect $nothing


[[ $field ]] && { # want field    
    echo "${items[field-1]}" # print the item
                             # (index justified for human use)
    exit;
}

[[ $list ]] && { # want list
    for index in $list; do
        echo -n "${items[index-1]}${delim}" # print the list 
                                            # (index justified for human use)
    done
    exit;
}

exit 1; # no field or list
```

Comment: Offtopic. Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MarcB Instead of deleting, can we just close it and let me leave a link to the codereview?

Comment: I see a lot of questions on the sidebar about scripting and CSV. This will be helpful even though it is "off topic".

Comment: It's only 43ms slow. on an intel atom. Nothing a user would ever notice in a small file around 100K or so.

Comment: Suggested improvement: `\n,\t,\r` expansion.

Comment: `iPos+=1` concatenates "1" to the string contained in the variable. If you really intend to increment an integer, you should use `((iPos += 1))` or `((iPos++))`.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson it seems you've missed the integer declaration of iPos. which is also why it begins with an i. I just verified that at the console.

Comment: does raise an interesting point. `tPos` (target position) has no defined value, so it isn't declare as an integer. By some miracle of bash scripting this still works though: `items[tPos++]=$value;` This is the kind of stuff you only learn after hours of manual hacking.

Comment: Another key note is that in a more robust RegEx implementation, the Accept Procedure would only be one line of code. Bash just doesn't have the power to test for blank lines in a multi-statement RegEx. Maybe it does if its the first RegEx in the OR `|` list. I know for a fact that worked at the console but didn't work in the code. I think i just gave up on trying to make the backslash work after I figured out the blank lines didn't work.

Comment: An array subscript is an arithmetic context. That's why `items[tPos++]=$value;` works. Similarly, using `(())` to explicitly set up an arithmetic context instead of using `declare -i` aids in readability and prevents errors such as mine. It also means you don't have to [improperly use Hungarian notation](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html). The key to making Bash regex matching work is to put the whole pattern in a variable and do something like `[[ $string =~ $pattern ]]`. You'll notice that there are *no* characters on the right hand side (which must not be quoted).

Comment: Okay.. I've been updating this code and will add your inputs. I've just removed the line loop with one call to `sed`. Output now accepts a field seperator and a list of fields to print. However, I'm not sure if I should update it here, on my pastebin, or at the code review. lol any suggestions to that effect?

Comment: I can't get 'nothing' (empty text) to match. I think an empty variable expansion is the reason for this because it works as a literal expression. The backslash only matches as a char class and the regex must be expressed as `[[ $string =~ ^$pattern$ ]]` or it won't match most of the inputs.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, I've pushed my latest updates. I've chosen to disambiguate the arithmetics with $[EXP] notation. Also added a few comments to help translators.

Comment: **Please do not cross-post questions;** doing so causes unnecessary hassle for us on both sites. If a question is off topic here but on topic on Code Review, flag it for migration. I'm closing this one on the spot since you have reposted it there, but I probably won't be deleting it.

Comment: `$[]` is deprecated. It should not be used for new scripts. The only similar use which is acceptable is for array subscripts. Use `$(())` or `(())` instead of `$[]`. `$pattern='^$'; [[ $string =~ $pattern ]]` or `[[ -z $string ]]` should work for "empty" strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seriously, the way to make it faster is to write in in a language that isn't interpreted.

A shell may be a poor choice for a parser for the same reason I wouldn't write an accounting package in 6502 assembly language, or an operating system in COBOL.

And, honestly, `awk` isn't going to be that much better. It's ideal for sequential text processing but it would be a stretch to apply it to something as complex as a parser.

Sometimes, you just have to rethink the tools you're using. If you can't do it is a compiled language like C, at least give some thought to a byte-code oriented language like Python.

Comment: well sure, but I'm not trying to parse the USGS terra server database.. just some small bash scripts. Compiled I could do in c or asm and I have actually. This is for a scripting project. So awk or bash unfortunately.

Comment: @Triston, my advice still stands. If you want speed, interpreted languages are not the best way to go. Or, looking at it another way, if you want a good project for a shell, recursive descent parsers probably aren't a perfect showcase.

Comment: I do have an AWK compiler as well. But like I said its just a script project.

Comment: Its good advice still, I totally agree. But binary is outside the domain of scripting. And that's the domain I'm restricted to.

Comment: and when I say super slow,... I mean 43ms. on an intel atom.

Comment: @Triston, 43ms? As in milliseconds? I'm not _entirely_ certain I'd consider that slow :-)

Comment: @TristonJ.Taylor you're definitely choosing the wrong language to solve your problem.   I can't believe you are really restricted to only shell (especially since you can launch, for example, awk).   If you give more details about the real constraints you are under, someone may be able to suggest an alternative that sucks less violently than shell for implementing a parser.

Comment: Well for one, I don't like binaries because of portability issues. For two, I'm trying to teach other's advanced techniques in shell scripting. So using a binary is self defeating. I'm going to take the time to learn awk and rewrite it there. Perl was one of the first languages I taught myself as a programmer and it is better suited for the task, but the CPAN seems to have lost its mind and traded everything good for complexity. Complexity I frown upon simplicity I cherish after 15+ years hacking at these consoles in over 10 different languages if you catch my drift sir.

Comment: Ill suited for the task it is... yet the language is portable and serves as an excellent example of code prototyping.

Comment: @paxdiablo I just went over some figures, parsing a file of 50 lines with 5 fields would take more than 10 seconds to retrieve all fields, therefore it is slow. Dumping all fields at once instead of singularly we can bring that down to around 2.5 seconds. I estimate with awk I can knock those figures down to about 45-275ms.

Comment: And those figures wouldn't exist without this 'foolish' prototype.

Comment: When some genius decides to invent the bash script compiler, people will look at this code and say: Behold! There's gold in them there hills! :D Happy hacking my friends.

Comment: I once wrote a csv parser in 32-bit assembler that could do 500,000+ lines of 20+ fields in about 1.5 seconds so... I know just how slow that really is :) It had its own memory block manager but didn't do a recursive parse because I didn't know what that was at the time. If you use windows and MASM you can find the modular code over at WinAsm.net. The project name is MCSL.